# Flask - How to deal with Chinese character in URL

Tags: python, flask, character-encoding, blueprint

I am using Flask to building a REST API, but when I pass query parameters with Chinese Character, I got garbled characters instead of Chinese

```py
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

class Keyword(Resource):
    def post(self, keyword):
        return {"keyword": "keyword"}

keyword_api = Blueprint('resourses.keyword', __name__)
api = Api(keyword_api)
api.add_resource(
    Keyword,
    '/keyword/<string:keyword>',
    endpoint='keyword'
)
```

```
POST http://localhost:5000/keyword/價錢
```

I expected the output of {"keyword": "價錢"}, but the actual output is {"keyword": "è²´é\u0081\u008e"}

Update:
Right now I added this to the code, it returns {"keyword": "價錢"} correctly

```
keyword = keyword.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('utf8')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to be functioning correctly. I have taken the liberty of modifying it a bit and make it into a working example. Important thing to notice is that **b'{"keyword": "\u50f9\u9322"}'** object type is bytes denoted by **b** prefix. If you serialize this data from json to python native string, you will find it is valid 價錢 encoded.

```
from flask import Blueprint, Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from werkzeug.local import LocalProxy
from logging import DEBUG

app = Flask(__name__)
app.logger.setLevel(DEBUG)
logger = LocalProxy(lambda: app.logger)


class Keyword(Resource):
   def post(self, keyword):
      logger.info("Keyword: {}".format(type(keyword)))
      return {"keyword": keyword}

keyword_api = Blueprint('resourses.keyword', __name__)
api = Api(keyword_api)
api.add_resource(
    Keyword,
    '/keyword/<string:keyword>',
    endpoint='keyword'
)

app.register_blueprint(keyword_api)
```

Comment: You're right, it was encoded, found it works when I encode with iso-8859-1 then decode with utf8, but not sure it's the right way to decode.

Comment: The issue is not with the content of keyword but rendering it on screen. You can use the keyword as it is.

Answer (score 0):

The type is `'utf-8'` but decoded by`'iSO-8859-1'`, so there are garbled characters. The `Bytes` data was decoded into `Str` by `'iso-8859-1'`. When you encoded it by `'iso-8859-1'`, it changed back to `Bytes` data again, then decoded it  by `utf-8`  and the  output was right. It's the change between different encoding/decoding types. You may set the decoding type to be `utf-8` if you find the corresponding parameters.